# How to delete from select in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, uniqueidentifier, subquery

This code doesn't work for MySQL 5.0, how to re-write it to make it work

```
DELETE FROM posts where id=(SELECT id FROM posts GROUP BY id  HAVING ( COUNT(id) > 1 ))
```

I want to delete columns that dont have unique id. I will add that most of the time its only one id(I tried the in syntax and it doesnt work as well).

Answer (score 262, accepted):

`SELECT` (sub)queries return result *sets*. So you need to use `IN`, not `=` in your `WHERE` clause.

Additionally, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/45498#45498) you cannot modify the same table from a subquery within the same query. However, you can either `SELECT` then `DELETE` in separate queries, or nest another subquery and alias the inner subquery result (looks rather hacky, though):

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE id IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT id FROM posts GROUP BY id HAVING ( COUNT(id) > 1 )
    ) AS p
)
```

Or use joins [as suggested by Mchl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562787/how-to-delete-from-select-in-mysql/4562863#4562863).

Comment: I had a table with 150 duplicate keys. I executed the above query and it said "144 rows affected", but there where still duplicate keys. So I executed the query again and it says 5 rows affected, again: 1 row affected. Then all the duplicate keys where gone. Why is this?

Comment: This is happening, because your are only deleting 1 entry out of each set of duplicates: `SELECT id FROM posts GROUP BY id HAVING ( COUNT(id) > 1 )`

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @thang: Which is why I said to alias the inner subquery.

Comment: No, still doesn't work.  If you don't alias the inner subquery, it gives you a different error message.  I ended up creating a temporary table, dumping everything to it, and then delete where id in that temp table.

Comment: @thang: Post a separate question. As it is there is nothing I can do if all you're going to give me is an error message and "doesn't work".

Comment: @thang: I tried it four years ago and just tried it again now, and it works.

Comment: I did the exact same thing.  Did you use innodb?  I wonder if it depends on the engine.

Comment: @thang: I tested it on both MyISAM and InnoDB and it works. What is your version of MySQL? I highly recommend posting a separate question so you can provide more details.

Comment: let me dig into it some more.  probably something stupid i am doing.  if it still doesn't work, i'll post a new question.  thanks!

Comment: Will you please explain what does the "As p" does?

Comment: @Samarth it is an alias for the derived table (SELECT id FROM posts GROUP BY id HAVING ( COUNT(id) > 1 ))

Answer (score 28):

```
DELETE 
  p1
  FROM posts AS p1 
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT ID FROM posts GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
) AS p2
USING (id)
```

Comment: This appears to work, but I'm confused by the syntax and can't find any resources elsewhere to explain it. `CROSS JOIN` apparently performs a cartesian join, so seems like this might do unnecessary work, or perform sub-optimally? Could anyone explain?

Comment: It will do a cartesian product only if there's no `USING` clause. With `USING` the product is limited to pairs having same value in `id` column, so it is in fact very limited.

Comment: Could you do the same thing with inner join? I.E. `DELETE 
  p1
  FROM posts AS p1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID FROM posts GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
) AS p2 ON p2.ID=p1.ID`

Comment: @Andrew: Yes. Functionally these joins are exactly the same.

Comment: @wintron `CROSS JOIN` is the same as `[INNER] JOIN` in MySQL; it doesn't implement `CROSS JOIN` in the way that ANSI SQL describes it. `SELECT ... FROM a JOIN b USING (x)` is syntactic sugar for `SELECT ... FROM a JOIN b ON b.x = a.x`.

Answer (score 14):

you can use inner join :

```
DELETE 
    ps 
FROM 
    posts ps INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT 
           distinct id 
         FROM 
             posts 
         GROUP BY id  
      HAVING COUNT(id) > 1 ) dubids on dubids.id = ps.id
```

Comment: This is great because it works for queries with a composite PK

Comment: When I tested in MySQL 5.7, this is more faster than BoltClock's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all duplicates, but one out of each set of duplicates, this is one solution:

```
DELETE posts
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(id) = 1

    UNION

    SELECT id
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(id) != 1
) AS duplicate USING (id)
WHERE duplicate.id IS NULL;
```