# MySQL select refactor

Tags: mysql

On MySQL, this does not run:

```
delete from robottinosino where date = (select max(date) from robottinosino);
```

Error message:

> ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'robottinosino' for
>   update in FROM clause

Question:

- *Why*? (emphasis on the "why" so the Q is not inaccurately marked as "duplicate")
- How to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562787/how-to-delete-from-select-in-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471277/mysql-delete-from-with-subquery-as-condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL doesn't allow you to delete from a table that you're also selecting from. It's a race condition in many cases - you could be deleting records from the table before the select part of the query has had a chance to retrieve them.

In your case, the query should be allowed, because there isn't any danger of this race, but MySQL isn't smart enough to figure that out.

There're a workarounds here: [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)