# Delete Query with SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I have been using 2 tables like this

```
tbl_songs
id | track_id | dummy_name

tbl_tracks 
id | song_id
```

I have duplicate dummy_name but my first record's value from set of duplicate records is updated to tbl_tracks like this.

```
tbl_songs s
id | track_id | dummy_name
 1 |       12 | A
 2 |          | A
 3 |          | A
 4 |      2   | B
 4 |          | B

tbl_tracks t
 id | song_id 
 2  | 4
 12 | 1
```

By Inner join relationship I have updated tbl_songs 's track_id column to find the duplicate records..

**NOTE** I want to delete those records that are with same dummy_name (i.e duplicate recods) and have `track_id = ''` or I can say that are not related with tbl_tracks.

My tried sql  for selecting records

```
SELECT a.id as aid, a.dummy_name as adn, b.id as bid, b.dummy_name as bdn
FROM tbl_songs a
LEFT JOIN tbl_songs b ON a.dummy_name = b.dummy_name
WHERE a.track_id != '' AND  a.dummy_name != '' AND a.id <> b.id
```

To delete these records

```
DELETE FROM tbl_songs where EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM tbl_songs a
LEFT JOIN tbl_songs b ON a.dummy_name = b.dummy_name
WHERE a.track_id != '' AND  a.dummy_name != '' AND a.id <> b.id)
```

Error: `You can't specify target table 'tbl_songs' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562787/how-to-delete-from-select-in-mysql

Comment: `DELETE FROM tbl_songs where id IN (
SELECT b.id
FROM tbl_songs a
LEFT JOIN tbl_songs b ON a.dummy_name = b.dummy_name
WHERE a.track_id != '' AND  a.dummy_name != '' AND a.id <> b.id)`

Ends with same error. I have tried it before

Comment: Added my error message at last.

Comment: I would question your schema while at it.  You have basically created a circular reference. Why does `tbl_tracks` need to reference `tbl_songs` when `tbl_songs` already has a reference to `tbl_tracks`?

Comment: tbl_tracks with `song_id` was my first reference. And it was absolutely correct. I referred second tbl_songs with `track_id` just to remove duplicate records. I will drop the column once I will finish my requirement.

Comment: greetings OP. If an answer helped you find the problem and for you to solve it, it is customary to tick it. cheers

Answer (score 1):

*If* I understand it well, you need to delete from `tbl_songs` all records such as `track_id = ''` if, and only if, there is an other record with the same `dummy_name` but having `track_id != ''`

```
DELETE FROM tbl_song 
    WHERE track_id = '' 
    AND dummy_name IN (SELECT dummy_name FROM tbl_song WHERE track_id != '')
```

Comment: I won't doubt if it would be so simple. I had this in my mind. I have some records in tbl_songs that are not duplicate but at same time they are not linked with tbl_tracks

Comment: @Sankalp I don't get that later case from your example. Could you update it?

Comment: I have some records in tbl_songs with dummy_name that are not repetative. and completely not linked with tbl_track table. That are unique with itself with no relation to tbl_tracks. I hope I am clear

Answer (score 0):

The error is a normal feature of MySQL. (i.e. you cannot be affecting a table and selecting over it in the same statement).

You can create a temp table with the IDs from the songs table (an incrementing int or whatever) then delete using:

`DELETE ... WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM temp)`

Or something similar to this. Reasonable?