# Delete selected rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-delete

I would like to delete set of rows, which have same property like this SQL select.

```
SELECT item_id, count(*) as item_in_order
FROM items
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING item_in_order = 1
```

In words it means, that I have items of orders and I would like to delete rows, which are from orders with only one Item.

For example:

```
item_id    order_id
1          1
2          2
3          2
4          3
5          3
6          4
```

So I would like to delete rows with item_id 1 and 6.

Comment: nt clear.. tell little more.. you want to delete the record which u can select using this select query??

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would like to delete set of rows form SELECT query that a post

Comment: This topic is silimar like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562787/how-to-delete-from-select-in-mysql , but query from this delete me each record. And I have got around 300k rows so query execution time was very long thanks to subslecet in subselect

Comment: I **fix it** with new temporary table with syntax: 
    INSERT items_temp 
      SELECT *
      FROM items
      GROUP BY order_id
      HAVING count(*)  > 1

Comment: yes  this is what I suggested u.. right.. !!

Comment: Bad message, I do not fix it, because I "copy" grouped data in new table

Comment: can you please make it more clear.. didn't get ur last comment..

Comment: Where is the `item_in_order` column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this query

```
delete from items
where order_id in 
   (SELECT order_id
    FROM items
    GROUP BY order_id
    HAVING count(*)  = 1
   )
```

it will delete the row where order_id exist only once in items table

Comment: Looks clear, I tried exactly this same but result is error:
eror in query (1093): You can't specify target table 'items' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Yes I use. Is possible delete from same query that I select? I do not understant it. I think it is similar like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: hey dont mind but for time being u can try by duplicating this table and after deleting the record just delete the duplicate table.. does it make any sense??