# PHP mysqli Find In Database and Delete all Record Relating to search

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-delete

looking for a little help, Im tring to write a search and delete code in php for databases

i need to do a search in a database and delete all found items "rows"
what i have been do is calling the table one by one and deleting the affected row.
im thinking there has to be a better way then this??

if you have any ideas this would be greatful

cheers thanks

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp. Look at the `WHERE` statement.

Comment: You'll need to use a `foreach` to loop over the found results. Something like `foreach ($result as $found) { $sql = "DELETE FROM your_table WHERE column=$found;";}`

Comment: Or something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4562797/ or http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-removing-eliminating-duplicates-from-a-mysql-table/ <= entry #21

Comment: `DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE yourSearchCondition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
$search = $_POST['txtboxname'];
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM tablenaem WHERE name like '%$search%'");
```