# Delete selected row from table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the best way to delete the results of this selection from the table?

```
select id from taxon2 as a 
   where rank = 'No Taxon' and 
   (select count(*) from taxon2 as b 
      where a.id = b.parentid) = 0;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete from select in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562787/how-to-delete-from-select-in-mysql)

Comment: No, that answer does not apply (or work) here. The a. and b. in the selection require a different answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
delete taxon2 
from taxon2
  left join taxon2 t2 on taxon2.id = t2.parentid
where t2.id is null;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2cfc/1)

And with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
delete from taxon2
where rank = 'No Taxon' 
   and not exists (
      select 1
      from (select * from taxon2) as b 
      where b.parentid=taxon2.id)
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a57f76)

Comment: @xpda -- glad that could help.  now that I see your `rdbms`, I've include an `outer join` solution as well.