# MySQL PDO Delete all rows returned by previous Select statment

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, delete-row, sql-delete

The initial select statement goes like this, and will return X number of rows:

```
$query = $database->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$query->execute();
while ($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
}
```

Now I want to delete all of the rows returned in a single statement without looping, but only the exact rows returned since additional records may be inserted during the execution of the script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete from select in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562787/how-to-delete-from-select-in-mysql)

Comment: @cmorrissey Nope! not a duplicate! Totally different!

Comment: how is it not a duplicate? you can simply delete all of the rows you want deleted with single MySQL call instead of looping though your results in php ... and I quote `Now I want to delete all of the rows returned in a single statement without looping`

Comment: What storage engine?  If you are using InnoDB then you can use a transaction.  Or you can lock the table to prevent new inserts.  Other than that, without looping, not sure what you can do (create a table of IDs to delete maybe).  what are you doing in the `SELECT` that you couldn't just delete the data right away?

Comment: @cmorrissey Sounds like cockadookie to me!

Comment: @Mr.Cockadookie cmorrisey is right this is a duplicate!