# Delete without alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I like to delete duplicates from a table `game`. There are entries with the same `playerId` and `timeParameter` and the ones with lowest `gameId` should remain.

I can query the entries with:

```
select a.`gameId` from `game` a
where not exists
  (select min(b.`gameId`) as m from `game` b
    group by b.`playerId`, b.`timeParameter`
    having m = a.`gameId`);
```

But I can't use the alis *a* in the delete statement:

```
delete from `game` a
where not exists
  (select min(b.`gameId`) as m from `game` b
    group by b.`playerId`, b.`timeParameter`
    having m = a.`gameId`);
```

Getting a syntax error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'a
where not exists
  (select min(b.`gameId`) as m from `game` b
    group by b.`' at line 1
```

This error tells me nothing, but I know that I can't use aliases in a delete statement.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: even you can not delete this by using select statement with same table

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562787/how-to-delete-from-select-in-mysql

Comment: @vertex if you like my ans  than can you up vote and accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a sub query and make one derived table

```
delete from game where gameId IN
(
select gameId from(
select a.`gameId` from `game` a
where not exists
  (select min(b.`gameId`) as m from `game` b
    group by b.`playerId`, b.`timeParameter`
    having m = a.`gameId`)
)tmp
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work: `ERROR 1093 (HY000): Table 'game' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data` as krishn patel said.

Comment: can you provide fiddle with sample data, I will give a try

Comment: It seems working. After deleting the same number of games remains as using the solution with the temporary table. I accept your answer because it uses only one statement.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct and per MySQL documentation if you are using alias then you will have to refer it in your `DELETE` statement. So either remove the alias `a` or make your `DELETE` statement like

```
delete a from `game` a ...
```

Quoting from [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)

> Note
>
> If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when
>   referring to the table:
>
> `DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1, test2 WHERE ...`

Answer (score 1):

Using @krishn patel idea to create a temporary table this should work.

First create a table *dontDeleteMe* which contains all gameIds that should remain.

```
create table `dontDeleteMe` as
      select min(`gameId`) as `theId` from `game`
      group by `playerId`, `timeParameter`;
```

Than I can use this table for a subquery:

```
delete from `game`
where `gameId` not in
  (select `theId` from `dontDeleteMe`);
```

And after that I can drop the temporary table:

```
drop table `dontDeleteMe`;
```

Comment: can you try @rahul ans  ?

Comment: you can make derived table and do it using single sql..this is bad idea