# Delete from mysql after select in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Probably it was similar question but I didn't find the right answer. I want to delete from table all rows with the same name but I want to get this name by ID. Here's what I'm doing in php:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT FROM projects WHERE id=?")) {

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $projectId);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $project_name);

   }


while( $row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt) ){

         $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "DELETE FROM projects WHERE name=?");
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $project_name);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   }
```

It doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: `SELECT FROM`...you forgot to specify any columns to select

Comment: P.s. if you turn on mysqli error reporting it'll tell you the problem immediately

Comment: P.s. why don't you just delete by ID if you already know the ID? Or could there be other rows with the same name which you also want to delete?

Comment: You might also want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562787/how-to-delete-from-select-in-mysql

Comment: it seems to be weird why you'd have to delete by name when you already have the id to target the row you'd want to be removed

Comment: There are several rows with the same name but different IDs. I need to delete all instances with the same name, but I pass the ID in order to avoid issues with names

Comment: Ok, I changed this one: "SELECT FROM projects WHERE id=?" to "SELECT name FROM projects WHERE id=?" but still the same

Comment: See my second comment...get yourself an error message. And/or do some debugging and ensure your query actually selected some rows

Comment: Also take note of the comments mentioning that you don't need two separate queries for this

Comment: You are getting out of sync error. Use buffered queries instead.

Comment: Enable error reporting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param